# Running Gulp Works on One Computer, Not Another

Tags: node.js, command-line, gulp

I've got a [project](https://github.com/realph/gulp-zero) of mine that works perfectly fine on my MacBook Air. When I run `gulp` it runs my default task and serves my site to me.

On my iMac however, when I `git clone` the same repo, `cd` into that directory and run `npm install`, it begins the install and then gives me this error.

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!
```

When I run `gulp`, I get this error:

```
Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
```

Any idea why this works on one computer and not the other? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried to install it? "npm install node-sass"

Comment: @alebruck I'm confused, because the `package.json` file doesn't mention node-sass, it's using gulp-sass.

Comment: @alebruck Okay, so it looks like node-sass is a gulp-sass dependency. Any reason why it's failing to install on `npm install`?

Comment: gulp-sass is a wrapper around node-sass. 

Take a look at package.json from gulp-sass, there is a dependency for node-sass https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/blob/master/package.json

Comment: @alebruck I've tried to do `npm node-sass` but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. Do you know of any reason why it work on one computer and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing libsass c bindings.
There are multiple reasons why this could be. Check that your npm version and node and gulp-sass and node-sass versions are identical.

There's also several issues, but I think this one fits your case best based on the vague description available. https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/174

Comment: Check that npm, node, gulp-sass and node-sass versions are identical locally within my project?

Comment: Installed each package individually and it looked like gulp-imagemin was causing the problem.